# Azure Logic App added http workflow component getting an Uri error

Tags: azure, http, azure-logic-apps

Part of the Azure Logic App workflow I need to send HTTPS request to our vendor site.
I use HTTP Workflow component and enter URL in the follwoing format:
https://username:password@www.website.com

I am getting the following error after workflow run:
InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'HTTP_2' inputs at line '0' and column '0': '**Error converting value** "https://username@company.com:password@webservices.somesystem.com/auth/authentication/generateSecureAPIToken" **to type 'System.Uri'. Path 'uri'.'.**

[image: This is how I created WebRequest component:]
[image: This is the Error]

Please help!

The same URL string, by the way works, when I copy and run in the Chrome browser.

Comment: Does your password contains any special character like **@**

Comment: Thanks for asking Ikhtesam - really need help! No, the password is ok, but the user name has the format of the email address, like xxx@company.com, so the full URL looks like this(I used only here h_ttps so that stackoveflow does not format my URL as a link.):
"h_ttps://myemail@company.com:password@webservices.xxx.com/auth/authentication/generateSecureAPIToken"

Comment: To add here. I even tried to set up  a logic app variable and hard code initial value equal to "name@email.com:password@" and on HTTP step concatenate variable with he https request. Did not help. Same error.

Comment: Can you replace the `@` in the username with `%40` and try?

Comment: I tried it, same problem. I found a way around my problem just a moment ago. Will post an answer shortly. Ikhtesam, thank you VERY much for your timely responses!!! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found. To get an answer I used a small bit of C# code to get me an encoded base-64 string:

```cs
var request = WebRequest.Create("https://websiteUrlWithoutUserNameAndPassword....com");

string authInfo = "username:password";

authInfo = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
```

From the C# debugger, take the value of `authInfo` string. Use it in your "Logic App" HTTP component as a header:

```
key: "Authorization"
value: the content of the "authInfo" string
```

[image: See on the picture below]